# Free Hardware and Software Logging Software

Tags: windows, hardware, desktop

Just wondering if anyone knows of some software that will log windows based computer hardware, software, license keys for OS, Word etc.  Preferable a exe that I can run that produces a html/text file or into a remote database for reference in case this PC ever returns to me for repair again (or I get a phone call so I can look up the customers computer spec) etc.

The idea is that I can build a database of customers computers that allows me to instantly look up their information about their computer, restore windows license keys etc and even generate a report which I can give to the user for their own reference.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://www.Spiceworks.com its is a free, agentless (aka nothing to install, it uses WMI to handle everything)  inventorying system that will do what your describing rather well.  It does reporting and can produce the reports in several different formats.  The inventory of software is rather handy and it can do some alerts as well (like if hard drives get too full or printers go below a certain % of toner)  Just setup the ip ranges you want it to scan and what account to use and it can do regular scans to update its information.