# How to get info about my network software & hardware?

Tags: networking, hardware

I have a lot of computers in my network and I need to get information about the software and hardware installed on all of them. In other words I want to have something like the pc network inventory, which can be generated just from my computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OCS inventory](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/) for doing that and much more if you interface it with [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en), both are opensource and are pretty easy to set up and get working.

Comment: I second OCS inventory - used by IT in my company, albeit it in a very limited fashion, and it definitely fits the bill of the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I used [NetCrunch](http://www.adremsoft.com/netcrunch/) quite often and it never disappointed me. It mostly uses SNMP for discovery and monitoring and it can recognize a wide range of devices. [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/) is also a great solution and it's free but never short of features. I recommend trying them both and see which one suits your particular needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two network monitoring tools to find out which machines are currently in your network segment:

[Nmap](http://nmap.org/)
It was designed to rapidly scan large networks, but works fine against single hosts. Requires WinPcap.

[Angry IP](http://www.angryip.org/w/About)
Is a very lightweight program that allows you to quickly scan a range of IP addresses. It provides less information and options than Nmap, but shows open ports and highlights which addresses are active.

(originally posted by [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc), I am moving this here from the now-deleted dupe question on SU)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Network Inventory Adviser by Clearapps is what you need. It can generate reports about all the software and hardware installed in the network.But it's not free.If you are looking for the free solution you can try Spiceworks.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/84481/free-hardware-and-software-logging-software) also has good information.

Answer (score 0):

[NEWT](http://www.komodolabs.com/) is a very useful network inventory tool.  You can run it free for up to 25 devices at a time.

If you have more than 25, the pricing is reasonable at a couple dollars per node.  Also, if you don't have that many more, say 40 machines, you can just run multiple scans on smaller ranges of your network (scan 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.120 then 192.168.1.121-192.168.1.40).  The negative of this is the reports are divided so you have to add up your totals if you want to see how many PCs have Office installed, or how many have IE8, etc.

If you are running this in a network without shared credentials, NEWT will still get basic information on the system.

However, if you are running a windows domain or have a common username/password setup on the machines, then NEWT can get very detailed information from each PC.

Answer (score 0):

As dmondark said, Spiceworks is pretty good.  If you want something that you can get going in under 15 minutes, it's hard to beat.